# Structure, with the same name as a Core Data object type?

Tags: swift

Can I have a structure with the same name as a Core Data object type? If so, how do I differentiate between the two in code?

Edit: For example, I have a `Track` core data object, and when I read in "track" information externally, it comes in via json. Instead of using the core data object, since its a managed object, I'm using another structure. I was planning on naming this `Track` as well, however this may result in conflicts which I'm not sure about, so at present I've called it `TrackStruct` instead. Also, is this the right approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need another `struct` when core data gives you a `ManagedObject` class having same name as the `Entity` in your xcdatamodeld? You could simply use the class reference for manipulating data from anywhere.

Comment: @nayem have you got an example? I've tried to use the core data classes in the past, but have always run into problems. I assumed this was because they were meant to be used as a managed object (always referencing a row in a table)? Thanks.

Comment: To add to this, I dont need to store this data in core data at all, and dont want to. Not sure if this is worth mentioning or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I've made a sample project for you after going through a lot of difficulties. But I'm posting the main concept here.

> You can have the sample project [here](https://bitbucket.org/m-i-n/json-modeling-with-coredataobjectmodel). Though I've loaded data from a local `.plist` file. You can check out the `loadPersonWithJSON(fromPath:)` function's job. Just follow my code commenting.

Suppose I've a **Person** Entity in my `Core-Data` with two `String` property `name` and `location`. From the json I'm getting array which is of type `[[String:Any]]`. Now I want to map my json data to the core data object model.

```
enum CoreDataError: String, Error {
    case NoEntity = "ERROR: No Entity, Check the Entity Name"
}

enum JSONError: String, Error {
    case NoData = "ERROR: no data"
    case ConversionFailed = "ERROR: conversion from JSON failed"
}

typealias personJSONObjectType = [[String:String]]

class PersonTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var person: [Person] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.loadPersonWithJSON(fromPath: "your json URL in String format")
    }

    func loadPersonWithJSON(fromPath jsonURLString:String) {
        guard let jsonURL = URL(string: jsonURLString) else {
            print("Error creating an URL from \(jsonURLString)")
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonURL) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                guard let data = data else {
                    throw JSONError.NoData
                }
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? personJSONObjectType else {
                    throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
                }

                // Here you have your json data. Now map this data to your model object.

                // First you need to have your shared App Delegate
                guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                    print("No shared AppDelegate")
                    return
                }

                // Use shared App Delegate to have the persistent containers view context as managed object context. This will be used to verify whether your Entity exists or not
                let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

                // Get the Entity in your core data model
                guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: managedObjectContext) else {
                    throw CoreDataError.NoEntity
                }

                let persons = json.map({ (personInfo) -> Person in

                    let personName = personInfo["name"] as? String              // use appropriate key for "name"
                    let personLocation = personInfo["location"] as? String      // use appropriate key for "location"

                    // Get your object as Core data Managed object.
                    let aPerson = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext) as! Person

                    // Manipulate core data object with json data
                    aPerson.name = personName
                    aPerson.location = personLocation
                    // Manipulation done

                    return aPerson
                })

                self.person = persons
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } catch let error as JSONError {
                print(error.rawValue)
            } catch let error as CoreDataError {
                print(error.rawValue)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

### Additional Resource

You can use the following table view data source method to check if that works:

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.person.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let aPerson = self.person[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = aPerson.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = aPerson.location
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Does using a manage object model like this cause any additional overhead compared to using the json directly, or putting it into a structure?

Comment: No. Not really. It's okay to do like this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good approach for that, to separate CoreData from business models. There is just this naming issue. So, I will just share my experience, is that CoreData entities a prefixed with `Managed` and the business models are as they are which leads to have this in your case:
`ManagedTrack` <-> `Track`.